# eleventy collections api - add collections dynamically

Tags: javascript, static-site, eleventy

I want to create collections dynamically in 11ty.js and for that i have a block of code like so

```js
eleventyConfig.addCollection("myGithub", (collection) => {
    const result = collection.getAll()[0].data.myGithub
    const tags = collection.getAll()[0].data.myGithub.tags
    tags.forEach(tag => {
      console.log('hello')
      eleventyConfig.addCollection(`tag${tag}`, (collection) => {
        const repos = collection.getAll()[0].data.myGithub.repos
        console.log('hello')
        return repos.filter(repo => {
          return repo.data.tags.includes(tag)

        })
      })
    });

    console.log(Object.keys(collection.getAll()[0].data.collections))

    return result
  })
```

but this seems to skip the inner `eleventyConfig.addCollection` as i don't see those `console.log` statements, and i am wondering if something in `11ty` is stopping me from doing this. if not, what am i doing wrong?

not always, but sometimes i also get an error like

```
UserConfigError: config.addCollection(HTML) already exists. Try a different name for your collection.
```

Comment: I assume you've confirmed that `tags` has an array of stuff, right?

Comment: @RaymondCamden yes i have

Comment: if you console tags.length, you see a number > 0?

Comment: @RaymondCamden yes

Comment: oh dumb question - does the _first_ hello log fire? Unsure based on your description

Comment: @RaymondCamden yes it does :)

Comment: Hey sorry I dropped this - any chance you can create a small repo that replicates the issue and share it?

Comment: @RaymondCamden hey! i have made a stackblitz project here -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/11ty-dteq28?file=.eleventy.js please check the console for logs

Comment: I tried like heck, but wasn't able to figure this out. The best I can see is that maybe Eleventy doesn't allow you to add a collection *inside* a call to add a collection. I missed that part initially. I'd suggest filing a bug report with a link to your test, although you could maybe also simply it it a bit to remove the dynamic aspect, just try to add B inside a call to add A.

Comment: @RaymondCamden thanks for much for trying, i really appreciate it! i think i will file an issue maybe on their github